# Image grid with hover effect

Tags: css, image

I made a image grid in HTML with a table.

I want to use css only

here's the HTML

```
<table id="mainwrapper" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><a href="tuin.html"><img src="images/biggerthumb/tuin12.png"/> <span><img width="50px" src="images/biggerthumb/tuin12.png"/> </span></a></td>
  <td><a href="rivier.html"><img width="50px" src="images/biggerthumb/rivier4.png" /> </a></td>
   <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"><a href="living.html"><img width="50px" 
    src="images/biggerthumb/living7.png" /><span><img width="50px" 
     src="images/biggerthumb/living7.png" /></span></a></td>
       <td rowspan="2"><a href="rivier.html"><img width="50px" 
        src="images/biggerthumb/rivier6.png" /><span><img width="50px" 
          src="images/biggerthumb/rivier6.png" /></span> </a></td></tr>
         <tr><td><a href="keuken.html"><img width="50px" 
       src="images/biggerthumb/keuken1.png" /><span><img width="50px" 
        src="images/biggerthumb/keuken1.png" /></span> </a></td>
         <td rowspan="2"><a href="living.html"><img width="50px" 
      src="images/biggerthumb/living5.png" /><span><img width="50px" 
         src="images/biggerthumb/living5.png" /></span> </a></td>
         <td><a href="slaapkamers.html"><img width="50px" 
      src="images/biggerthumb/kamer1.png" /><span><img width="50px" 
      src="images/biggerthumb/kamer1.png" /></span> </a></td></tr></table>
```

But now I want to enlarge the Image in the table cells when someone hover on it. But the image need to be in front of the other images.

here's 
I tried  with

```
td > a > img:hover {

        vertical-align: top;
        z-index: 100;
        position: absolute;
               }
```

but that didn't work. The images need to enlarge on the same place as the original fixed image.

thanks a lot  !

Comment: show us your html

Comment: Do you have a code that you are working on?

Comment: Do you want the image to show lightbox-style, or just a bit larger? Use flexbox instead of tables (which are not best practice for layouts), and transform the image with scale. There are many CSS-only examples on the web that do just this. Give it a try and post your results, with code.

Comment: @dave Everitt they just need to enlarge a bit. But the other image can't move... so the image need to enlarge above the others...

Comment: Use CSS transform: scale() and flexbox instead of a table (much simpler!). Search “css only image gallery enlarge” and you’ll see many good examples you can adapt :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transform`:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp

```css
td > a > img:hover {
 transform: scale(1.5);
}
               
td > a > img{
transition: transform .2s;
}
```

```html
<table id="mainwrapper" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
 <td>
    <a href="slaapkamers.html">
      <img width="50px"src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" />
    <span><img width="50px" 
      src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" />
      </span> 
    </a>
  </td>
    <td>
    <a href="slaapkamers.html">
      <img width="50px"src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" />
    <span><img width="50px" 
      src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" />
      </span> 
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks it worked, I just added transform position for a better result

Comment: happy to help:)